# What is this metal cage covering the rear derailleur?

Tags: derailleur-rear, terminology

On my MTB: This cage like thing covering the rear derailleur was loose and was making a lot of noise when I was riding. I removed it temporarily and it seems fine to do so. Am I correct?

What is the technical name of this component and why is it present?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's known as a derailleur guard.  It is designed to protect your derailleur against side impacts that may damage it.

It's not a problem to remove it, i've never had one myself, nor do I know anyone that has had one and our derailleurs are all still fine.

It's probably a handy thing to have if you are parking your bike in large communal bike shelters where other users are perhaps not as careful as they could be.

Comment: it is one of those things that are hard to search for when you don't know the name. now that I know it is a derailleur guard, I see a lot of material. thanks!

Comment: Additionally, it protects against side impacts from dropping the bike right-side down on the ground.   Protection extends to the hanger as well as the mech.

Comment: It will protect your derailleur and its hanger but at the cost of endangering the frame.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава are you sure? I think it would need to be a very fragile frame and a very solid guard.

Comment: My experience is they are build soft, more often than not, the protector bends and jams the derailleur, has to be removed and is never replaced.  However, I have seen a couple of cases where removing a bent protector would have been a better outcome for the rider - car rack and bicycle stand, not riding inflicted damage.